# memory management for vector in c++ when vector is tje global variable

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, global-variables

I am working on a large C++ code base which I am compiling with Borland C++ (6.0) Builder. I injected the code so that when I execute a scenario, every method that gets hit can be recorded.
For that reason, I keep a global vector and did forward import of the file that holds the global variable.

The header file(Global.h) having the global variable-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern vector<string> tracerVector;
```

and the implementation file, Global.cpp-

```
#include "Global.h"

vector<string> tracerVector;
```

I include the header file in all the files, that I want to trace.

The following is just a sample injected method.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Product.h"
#include "Global.h"

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TmainForm *mainForm;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TmainForm::TmainForm(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner)
{
    TComponent *senderObj = (TComponent*)Owner;
    std::string injection = ("Type:" + AnsiString(senderObj->ClassName()) + " Object:" + AnsiString(senderObj->Name)).c_str();  
    std::string finalStatement = (injection + " methodName:TmainForm").c_str();
    if(!tracerVector.empty()){ 
     if(tracerVector.back() != finalStatement){
        tracerVector.push_back(finalStatement);
        }
    }
    else if(tracerVector.empty()){
        tracerVector.push_back(finalStatement);
    }
}
```

When the scenario that is small in terms of no. of required methods, it works fine but if the no. of required methods gets larger, I get the following exception-

```
size_type size() const { return this->_M_finish - this->_M_start; }
```

I suspect my global vector size is triggering this exception. Please suggest me how can I hold the whole execution path. I need to write the contents of this global vector to a file when an execution is complete and the user exits the application.

Comment: sounds like a static initialization order fiasco issue.  Without a [mcve] though we can't really say.

Comment: not sure what information should I provide to make my problem more understandable. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: Please provide the actual error you are getting. You only provided a line of code from the standard library instead of the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said exception, not error. I edited my post and the exception is what I provided in the post.

Answer (score 0):

What @NathanOliver means is detailed in the book of Effective C++ from Scott Meyers in Item 4.

If you have a static global object, as your case, and if you use it between different translation units the object may be uninitialized in some of them. It is because the relative order of initialization of nonlocal
static objects defined in different translation units is undefined

A translation unit is the source code with all of its includes from which an object file is generated.

A solution to wrap the initialization inside a function such like a singleton pattern:

```
vector<string>& initTrace() 
{ 
    static vector<string> tracerVector; 
    return tracerVector;
}
```

Comment: The static variable should not be a reference.

Comment: @Natasha you can do initTrace().push_back() or you can do vector<string>& v = initTrace(); v.push_back()